# How do i install Handbrake in Ubuntu? I get the 404 page not found with ppa

Tags: ubuntu, http-status-code-404, handbrake

How do I solve this 404 error. Is there any alternate method to install Handbrake? I also tried to uncheck it in software updates i dont know what it does but still i did and found no use with it.

Answer (score 0):

please try it:

> $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases
>
> $ sudo apt-get update
>
> $ sudo apt-get install handbrake-gtk

source: https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/ubuntu/handbrake-releases

Answer (score 0):

Handbrake is in the default repositories in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install handbrake
```

Handbrake can be installed as a snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To find the handbrake snap package open the terminal and type:

```
snap find handbrake # the next 2 lines are the results of the command
Name          Version  Developer  Notes  Summary
handbrake-jz  1.0.2-0  jz         -      The open source video transcoder
```

The results of `snap find handbrake` will usually show that the version of handbrake-jz is the latest stable version of Handbrake. To install this handbrake snap package run these commands:

```
sudo snap install handbrake-jz
```

handbrake and handbrake-jz can also be installed from the Ubuntu Software app in Ubuntu 16.04 and later.

Answer (score 0):

Your best using the PPA as @Andres311 suggested.

The version of HandBrake in the Ubuntu Repositories is not maintained by the HandBrake Team and has bugs that do not occur in the official PPA Release.

See https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/1.1.0/get-handbrake/where-to-get-handbrake.html